# Cannot scan with Canon MX300, but I can print

Tags: scanner, canon

I've got a Canon MX300 (not that new printer, but it used to work perfectly through Windows). Now I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop and I managed to make it printing, but not scanning.

I think I checked all the links I found, but apart from following these tips https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/05/canon-printer-scangear-mp-ubuntu-20-04/
there wasn't much more.

I've got the icon of "Canon printer setup utility 2" among the icons but when I click on it, it doesn't work at all, nothing opens up!

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Ciao.

I have an issue like you. The `simple scan` application solve all my problems.

Try with `apt install simple-scan`

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to grab [the `sane-pixma` libraries](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man5/sane-pixma.5.html) to get that device working:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Install the `sane` packages:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xsane sane sane-pixma
   ```
2. Open Sane

Based on [the documentation](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man5/sane-pixma.5.html), your scanner is supported by this package

Answer (score 0):

So, thanks to both of you! I tried

```
sudo apt-get install xsane sane sane-pixma
```

but the terminal couldn't locate the package `sane-pixma`

When i tried to install `simple scan` the terminal answered it was already installed.

In the end i've just had a look up among the default utilities of the sistem and i found the app "Document scanner" and it worked perfectly.

In the end i was just distracted. I'm a beginner. Thanks anyway guys!